# How to rotate a gradient rather than the whole div?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have this gradient on element, and am trying to rotate only the gradient, but when I try to rotate it, as you see in the snippet, the whole element is rotating.

Any ideas?

```css
#test {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  color: #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #003366;
  background-image: none, linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  I'm gonna be some buttons and stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a hover or click effect? why can't you just adjust the gradient at the first place.

Comment: @Stickers I was wondering the same, but was making sure I wasn't crazy. If you're going to rotate the gradient a full 180 (which would basically be backwards), why not just switch up the `rgba`?

Comment: @RobScott, because I don't know how to switch up the rgba

Comment: @Chris just switch up the order of the `rgba`. Instead of `linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)`, use `linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, .6)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use degree with `linear-gradient` to rotate it. In this case you have to use **0deg** (or `to top`) because the default value of linear-gradient is `to bottom` which is **180deg**

```css
#test {
  color: #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #003366;
  background-image:linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  I'm gonna be some buttons and stuff
</div>
```

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) the syntax is:

```
linear-gradient([ [ [ <angle> | to [top | bottom] || [left | right] ],]? <color-stop>[, <color-stop>]+);
```

Where

> `<angle>`
>
> The gradient line's angle of direction. A value of 0deg is
>   equivalent to to top; increasing values rotate clockwise from there.

Comment: in my snippet, i already have the color rotated, but the content rotated as well. Sorry, I should have been clearer in my post

Comment: @Chris yes and you can rotate the gradient whith the code i provided :)

Comment: @Chris check again or more details ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want to rotate the [gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) (I think). The default is 180 degrees, so something like:

```
background-image: none, linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
```

Though, for 180 degrees you can just reverse the color order

Comment: pay attention as 180degre is already the default value of the linear-gradient